# How to format String to conform to PreparedStatement Acceptable format for insertion

Tags: java, sql

I'm currently working on a project that requires me building a class for uploading data details from a file into a prepared table in a database. So far so good, I have done well, but my challenges has been to format the data to insert to the acceptable format of an sqlite statement in java. Here is my code...

```
import java.io.*;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Data_Update {

    Connection conn = JavaConnect.Connecrdb();

    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    File c;

    Data_Update(File d) {

        this.c = d;

    }

    boolean testFile() {

        System.out.println(c.getName().substring(c.getName().length() - 4, c.getName().length()));

        boolean t = c.getName().substring(c.getName().length() - 4, c.getName().length()).equals(".sql");

        return t;

    }

    boolean createTable() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {

        String r = "", p, q = "";

        try {

            FileInputStream h = new FileInputStream(c);

            DataInputStream k = new DataInputStream(h);

            BufferedReader j = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(k));

            while ((p = j.readLine()) != null) {

                String s = "";

                if ((p.startsWith("("))) {

                    while (!s.contains(")")) {

                        s = s + p;

                    }

                    if (s.contains(", \'")) {
                        System.out.println("Yes");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No");
                    }

                    s.replaceAll("\'str\'", "\'\"+str+\"\'");

                    s.replace(", \'", ", \'\"+");

                    s.replace("\',", "+\"\',");

                    s.replace("(\'", "(\'\"+");

                    s.replace("\')", "+\"\')");

                    s.replace("),", ")");

                    System.out.println(s);

                    pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into courseinformation (currentsession, regno, fullname, level, previouscourses, gpa, 

    outstandingcourses, proposedcourses, totalcourseno, totalunit, registered, pre_userid, dept, sch, registrationpin, refdatetime) 

    values "  + s);

       pst.execute();

                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

            return false;

        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

The result has been that the final strings after all the replacements could not meet the standard of sql statement for inserting records

Answer (score 0):

With the given one can hardly create an immediately functioning piece of code, but you might start with this as a basis.

It seems you read SQL with quotes, commas and brackets, and try to make some String containing quasi-java with plus and double quote. That is thought too far: simple SQL works.

Though here I do not build an SQL text fragment, but split the input line in single values to be set.
This can be extended to field validation, and string-to-specific-type conversion.

The first step is to do all executions in a ***single* transaction**. That is a large speed-up. That means that there is one commit at the end, and hence autocommit for every statement has to be set to false. And on an exception a rollback.

One defines the PreparedStatement in advance.

Using try-with-resources (`try (X x = ...) { }`) automatically closes the resource (`x`).

Here I made some assumptions on the data. Like comma not being in the input as part of text values.

InputStreamReader without giving an encoding will take the local platform encoding, which is non-portable: the same file on another PC might be read with the wrong encoding.

There is neither field validation nor conversion, always using `setString`.

```
public void createTable(Connection conn, File c) throws IOException, SQLException {
    final int fieldCount = 16;
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    try (PreparedStatement  pst = conn.prepareStatement(
            "insert into courseinformation (currentsession, regno, fullname, level, "
            + "previouscourses, gpa, outstandingcourses, proposedcourses, "
            + "totalcourseno, totalunit, registered, pre_userid, dept, sch, "
            + "registrationpin, refdatetime) "
            + "values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")) { // 16 columns

        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(c), "UTF-8"))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // Assume that line is "  ('...', ..., '...'),"
                line = line.replaceFirst("^\\s*\\((.*)\\),?\\s*", "$1").trim();
                String[] fields = line.split(",\\s*", fieldCount);
                for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; ++i) {
                    String field = fields[i].trim().replaceFirst("^'(.*)'$", "$1");
                    pst.setString(1 + i, field); // SQL column nos counted from 1.
                }
                pst.execute();
            }
        }
        conn.commit();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        conn.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.replace` and `String.replaceAll` does not change your `String` object, they return new String after replacing, so you should write `s = s.replace...`

there are lot of other issues in your code, for example

```
                while (!s.contains(")")) {

                    s = s + p;

                }
```

is infinite loop if `p` does not contain `)`

also, manually escaping strings is wrong way of using sql api in java, you should use placeholders and binding parameters to your statements.